# How to get a current class name and methods that executed in the class file using testNg listeners?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm doing some customization in testNG report, and want to get a things in the below format:

```
Map<String className, List<list_of_invoked_methods_in_a_class>

Example:

I have a classA(Methods: test1,test2), classB(Methods: test3,test4);
output will be:

Map.put("classA",List<test1,test2>);
Map.put("classB",List<test3,test4>);
```

I want to do this by using TestNg listeners nor reflection or other ways.

Is there any listener in testNG api to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ITestResult`, `ITestContext` and `IMethodInstance` which can give you class name and method name which are using.

```
for (ITestResult testResult : testResultSet) {
    String methodName = testResult.getName() + "(";
    for (Object arg : testResult.getParameters()) {
        methodName += arg == null ? "" : arg.toString() + ", ";
    }

    uniqueMethodMap.add(testResult.getName());
    methodList.add(testResult.getParameters().length > 0 ?    methodName.substring(0, methodName.length() - 2) + ")" : methodName + ")");
}
```